# Resolving latency issues between a background thread and the UI thread in C#/WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I was asked this question in an interview and still not sure what the correct answer is. The question was:

"If you have a live streaming feed of data that needs to be passed from the background thread to the UI, how do you resolve latency issues between the 2 threads?"

I have read about different types of locks, where multiple threads can access an object simultaneously, however I'm not sure if this is correct as a lock might not be needed. You could just put the data on the dispatcher to send it to the UI.

Does anyone know the answer to this?

Comment: They might have wanted to here about the thread-safe collections in [System.Collections.Concurrent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

I believe the right response for this question is: What latency issues?

It's impossible to answer this question without more information - how the two threads communicate, and what latency issues exist.